# If $f : A \to B$ and $B$ is countable, given that $f$ is surjective, $A$ is countable.

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

I'm attempting to prove this statement, and I'm not sure if my deductions make sense, so I'd very much appreciate it if anyone could critique, comment or (most probably) improve my train of thought.

Since we're given that $B$ is countable, then by definition there must exist some $g$ s.t. $g : \mathbb{N} \to B$, with $g$ surjective. Then, it must be the case that $A$ is similarly countable because since $B$ is countable, and $f : A \to B$, for this to hold it's necessary that $A\subseteq \mathbb{N}$. Because $\mathbb{N}$ is countable, then $A$ is countable.

Again, I'm definitely not sure that is correct, I'm still getting my head around how exactly I'm supposed to prove statements like these, so any criticism would be amazing.

Comment: Why is it necessary that $A\subseteq\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: The statement is not true (take a constant function with domain $\Bbb R$).

Comment: @EricWofsey Maybe I denoted it wrong, I was trying to think about the definition of countability, with the countable set having to have the same cardinality of some subset of $\mathbb{N}$

Comment: @DavidMitra So would an appropriate counter example be a surjection $f : \mathbb{R} \to B$, with $B$ being some finite set (i.e. a singleton set)?

Comment: it is true however that if $B$ is countable and $f:B\to A$ is surjective, then $A$ is countable, assuming the axiom of countable choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement is incorrect. A counterexample is $A = \mathbb{R},\, B = \mathbb{Z}$, and $f(x) = [x] = \max \{ z \in \mathbb{Z} \, : \, z \le x\}$.

As to critique - your proof attempt *"Then, it must be the case that A is similarly countable because since B is countable ..."* consists mainly of restating what is to be proved.